# No Update in MariaDB on System-Versioned tables if the data is the same

Tags: mariadb, sql-update

Is there a way to tell MariaDB to not Update a row in System-Versioned Tables, if the data did not change?

I have a batch job that sets the correct status in my table, and I don't want to always check if this status is already set. Right now, I generate a history entry every time.

I'm looking for a general solution because this is just an example and I do similar things regularly.

I'm using MariaDB 10.7.3 but I guess it´s the same in every version.

Comment: is `update tbl set A=Z,B=Y where A!=Z or B!=Y` a pattern that can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System versioned tables are defined in SQL 2011 and require that each transaction (regardless if a row/column was modified/updated by same values or not) will be stored in history log. There is no setting to change or disable this.

As danblack pointed out, you could either modify the statement by specifying an excluding where clause or an impossible where clause. In both cases the update statement will not be executed and no history logs will be written.